# Identifying some quotient rings

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, ring-theory, ideals

How come that $k[w,z]/(w^2+z,w^3 z^2)\cong k[w]/(w^7)$?
Also why is $(xz,w)=(x,w)\cap(z,w)$ in the polynomial ring in 3 variables? what are the rules of ideal calculus making these results evident?

Comment: $P\in (xz,w)\iff xz \mid P \lor w \mid P \iff (x\mid P \land z\mid P)\lor w \mid P \iff (x\mid P \lor w\mid P)\land (z \mid P \lor w \mid P) \iff P\in (x,w) \land P\in (z,w) \iff P\in (x,w)\cap (x,w)$

Comment: And for the isomorphism, since you quotient by $w^2+z$, it's as if $z=-w^2$. And then $w^3z^2=-w^7$. And you can obviously remove the minus when quotienting. That's not formal, but you must have somewhere in your notes something that says "If $p(P,Q)$, then $k[w,z]/(P,Q)=(k[w,z]/(P))/(\pi(Q))$ where $\pi$ associates its class in $k[w,z]/(P)$ to any element in $k[w,z]$".

Comment: @DoktorFotzenglotz : I haven't had a class on that yet but it felt natural. But apparently, it just works without requiring any property $p(P,Q)$... http://www.ucl.ac.uk/~ucahmki/quotient.pdf

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The second question first: why is $(xz,w) = (x,w) \cap (z,w)$ as ideals of $k[x,y,z]$?

Note that $(xz) = (x) \cap (z)$ is easy (either as ideals of $k[x,z]$ or as ideals of $k[w,x,z]$) since these three ideals are all principal and $x$ and $z$ are relatively prime. Because of that, $$f \in (xz) \iff xz \mid f \iff x \mid f \land z \mid f \iff f \in (x) \cap (z).$$
This doesn't translate immediately to $(xz,w) = (x,w) \cap (z,w)$, since $f \in (xz,w)$ only means that $f = xzg + wh$ for some polynomials $g, h$.

Nevertheless, the additional $w$ is harmless and taking the quotient by $(w)$ exploits this nicely. For ideals of $k[w,x,z]$ containing $(w)$ correspond to ideals of $k[w,x,z]/(w) \cong k[x,z]$ and this correspondence preserves inclusions. Now $(xz,w)$ corresponds to $(xz)$, $(x,w)$ to $(x)$, and $(z,w)$ to $(z)$ and because $(xz) = (x) \cap (z)$ as ideals of $k[x,z] \cong k[w,x,z]/(w)$, this automatically gives $(xz,w) = (x,w) \cap (z,w)$ as ideals of $k[w,x,z]$.

Now for the first question. One ingredient is indeed, as xavierm02 indicates in the comments, that $\bar w^7 = 0$ in the quotient $k[w,z]/(w^2 + z, w^3z^2)$. Another ingredient is that, in general $R[z]/(z + a) \cong R$ for an arbitrary ring $R$ and arbitrary $a \in R$.

Now, for the full argument, start by noting that
$$k[w,z]/(w^2 + z, w^3 z^2) = k[w,z]/(w^2 + z, w^7).$$
This is really an equality: the ideals $(w^2 + z, w^3 z^2)$ and $(w^2 + z, w^7)$ are equal. It is possible to see by explicitly showing that $w^7 \in (w^2 + z, w^3z^2)$ and that $w^3 z^2 \in (w^2 + z, w^7)$. Computations in the quotient ring, however, make this much easier.

For, in the ring $k[w,z]/(w^2 + z, w^3 z^2)$, $\bar z = - \bar w^2$ and $\bar w^3 \bar z^2 = 0$, and therefore $\bar w^7 = \bar w^3(-\bar w^2)^2= 0$, which means that $w^7 \in (w^2 + z, w^3 z^2)$.

And, in the ring $k[w,z]/(w^2 + z, w^7)$, also $\bar z = -\bar w^2$ and $\bar w^7 = 0$, so $\bar w^3 \bar z^2 = \bar w^3(-\bar w^2)^2 = \bar w^7 = 0$, which means that $w^3 z^2 \in (w^2 + z, w^7)$.

Finally, continuing from $k[w,z]/(w^2 + z, w^7)$, first take the quotient by $(w^7)$ and then by $(w^2 + z)$.
$$k[w,z]/(w^2 + z, w^7) \cong (k[w,z]/(w^7))/(w^2 + z) \cong (k[w]/(w^7))[z]/(z + w^2) \cong k[w]/(w^7).$$